# Cakephp Date format output

Tags: cakephp, date, format

I'm trying to display the date in DMY format and database is stored as YMD format. how can I change into DMY format? If I've to use form helper how to I exactly use to display?
This is my code for display.

```
    <?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($jobtasks as $jobtask):
    $class = null;
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
        $class = ' class="altrow"';
    }
?>
    <table><tr>
    <td><?php echo $jobtask['Jobtask']['date']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Time class:

At the beginning of your php file write:

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;
```

And when you want to print the date:

```
<?php 
   $time = new Time($jobtask['Jobtask']['date']); 
   echo $time->format('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the time helper:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1471/Formatting

nice(), niceShort() or just format()

Answer (score 0):

try this code its work for you....it's store date field time in format DMY that you need...

```
<td><?php echo date('D M Y', strtotime($jobtask['Jobtask']['date'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include an explanation of what this does and how it solves the problem?